# Unable to blank cookies in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I am having a problem with cookies not disappearing on a site I am working on. I setup a page where a user registers. When they register, a cookie is set with the username to show them as logged in. That is working fine. However, when I try to make the cookie blank, and go back the main page, the cookie still shows as having a value set for it.

This is how I set the cookie:

`$_cookie["username"] = $user;`

And this is how I am trying to blank it:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
unset($_COOKIE['username']);}
```

I put in a couple of echos on the page that blanks the cookie to make sure it works and it shows that the cookie is set to nothing. But, when I go to a different page, the cookie is still set.

Not sure if this matters or not, but I have a menu page that is included in other pages like this:

`<?php require("menu.php");?>`

I took that out and tested it, but still had the same problems. I also tried it on different pages, and it seems to happen on all of them. I also tried setting the cookie like this:

`$_cookie["username"] = "";`

Had the same issue, though.

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `$_cookie` is not valid

Comment: It is actually $_COOKIE. Just forgot to capitalize it when I typed it in. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You may Try this:

```
            if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
            unset($_COOKIE['username']);
            setcookie('username', null, -1, '/');
            return true;
            } 
            else {
            return false;
            }
```